# Rig created after character was rigged with metarig can´t drive the metarig animation

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

My rig generated form my metarig does not drive the bones. if I rig my mesh the bones move it, but the rig does not move the bones. how to fix this ? [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I managed to parent the rig to the metarig. now my problem is that when I try to load a mixamo animation to the rig, using Expy kit, the arms of the character get crossed in opposite directions.  How to fix it ?

Comment: Rigify rigs are used like this: 1) The metarig is positioned to match the character mesh. 2) The rig is generated.  3) The character mesh is parented to the rig.  The rig is not parented to the metarig. Please add your blend file to your question and edit the post to match your current problem. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))